# R Studio error "Error: \554 exceeds maximum allowed octal value \377 (<input>:1:32)"

Tags: r

I am a novice R user trying to get started. I keep running into the error below trying to run script or calling in a dta Stata file:
Error: \554 exceeds maximum allowed octal value \377 (:1:32)

example below:

```
install.packages("foreign") 
library(foreign)
mydata <- read.dta('C:\DAta\Other data files\2022\2022.dta')
```

Then I receive the error:

```
Error: \554 exceeds maximum allowed octal value \377 (<input>:1:32)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but it is the first search result. So for others who come here, this is the solution:

You need to escape `\` in the path with a double `\\`. So the correct path from the question would need to be given like this:

```
mydata <- read.dta('C:\\DAta\\Other data files\\2022\\2022.dta')
```